# Throw item at specific distance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game, like a fire fighter, here is scenario in which player has to extinguish the fire through cloth, I had successfully made a cloth, and I am able to pick it but when I throw it, it doesn't throw, it remained there.
Here I want to throw cloth at fire(specific distance). Here is the code I did so far.. Any suggestion, where is the problem? Or what to do?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class pickup : MonoBehaviour {
public Transform OnHand;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown ("E")) {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity=false;
        this.transform.position = OnHand.position;
        this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find ("FPSController").transform;
        this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find ("FirstPersonCharacter").transform;

    }           
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        this.transform.parent = null;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity=false;
//      Rigidbody.AddForce (new Vector2(1,4), ForceMode.Impulse);
    }   
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have everything pretty much correct. You referred to the Rigidbody correctly to turn off the gravity, but then tried referring to the rigidbody incorrectly to add force.

Do GetComponent().AddForce (new Vector2(1,4), ForceMode.Impulse);

I don't see why that wouldn't work. Take out the '//' of course. 
Also, for optimization purposes, you can store the rigidbody in awake or start, than use the variable instead of using GetComponent several times.

something like rb = GetComponent();
then you can just use rb.AddForce().

Hope it helps! If it does, if you can mark it as the correct answer and upvote, do others know it has been answered :).